# Getting next month with date command?

Tags: bash, date

I had this in one  of my scripts which I'm sure has been working for ages. Today its saying next month is May?

```
#date
Mon Mar 31 15:30:13 BST 2014

#date +"%B %Y" --date="+1 month"
May 2014
```

Anyone know what the problem is - is there a better "next month" script I should use?

Comment: The funny thing is that if you do +2 months you also get May. This is because it checks today's date on next month, and April has 30 days.

Comment: Guess that not the best command to use to get next month then.

Comment: You can use `cal`. This a bit stupid, but `cal -A1  | awk '{print $3; exit}'` makes it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the [GNU](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Relative-items-in-date-strings.html) man pages:

> The fuzz in date units can cause problems with relative items. For example, ‘2003-07-31 -1    month’ might evaluate to 2003-07-01, because 2003-06-31 is an invalid date. 
>   To determine the previous month more reliably, you can ask for the month before the 15th of the current month

You can use a day which exists in all months:

```
date +"%B %Y" --date="$(date +%Y-%m-15) next month"
```

Result:

```
April 2014
```

Comment: Maybe you could also explain that the reason for getting `May` is that `April` doesn't have 31 days.  So the month is bumped up.

Comment: I was getting to that but @Broslow beat me to it

Comment: @Timmah Added it to the answer.  Comments are like post-it notes.  Those aren't searchable either.

Comment: To get only month year `date +"%m%Y" --date="$(date +%Y-%m-01) next month")`

Comment: On MacOS you need to use gdate from the GNU [coreutils](https://macappstore.org/coreutils/).

Answer (score -3):

To find previous month, the command:

```
date -d "-1 months" +%Y/%-m/%-d
```

will give you 2018/2/22 on 2018/3/22
and

```
date -d "-1 days" +%Y/%-m/%-d
```

will give you 2018/3/21

You can add or subtract as many months or days you like. If you subtract enough months it will go to last year.

Comment: but the problem lies on calculating those dates on a day 31th, where the calculation of +1 month may result in 1st of May, since April only has 30 days and the internals of the calculation are not clear. That's why Timmah's answer nails it by shifting to the 15th of the month, so that you are sure the other month will also have that date.