# How I can get the next month in shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, date

I would like to get the current and next months using shell script, I have tried this command:

```
$ date '+%b'

mar

$ date +"%B %Y" --date="$(date +%Y-%m-15) next month"

March 2018
```

But it always displays only the current month.

Could you please help me if there is something wrong with the commands.

Comment: No repro for me, your code returns `April 2018`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22764358/bash-getting-next-month-script/22764898#22764898

Comment: no ,maybe the version of solaris is 5.2

Comment: Does solaris except `"$(date +%Y-%m-15) + 30 days"` as a date?

Comment: @achref05, you tagged this "Linux". Solaris is not Linux.

Answer (score 5):

```
$ date -d "next month" '+%B %Y'
April 2018
```

Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22764358/bash-getting-next-month-script/22764898#22764898) about specific caveats

Note: your command works just fine for me (archlinux, bash4, date GNU coreutils 8.29)

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/22764898, it looks like this can return wrong results if run on 31st of a month

Comment: sorry, it does not work on solaris 5,2, but it works on centOS. what I should change ?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't rely on `date` alone to do this. Instead, perform a little basic math on the month number.

```
this_month=$(date +%-m)  # GNU extension to avoid leading 0
next_month=$(( this_month % 12 + 1 ))
next_month_name=$(date +%B --date "2018-$next_month-1")
```

Since you are using `bash`, you don't need to use `date` at all to get the current month; the built-in `printf` can call the underlying date/time routines itself, saving a fork.

```
$ printf -v this_month '%(%-m)T\n'
$ echo $this_month
3
```

Comment: It would be nice if you put related links for doc about this syntax of `printf` (for date query)

Comment: Frankly, I find GNU `date`'s barely-documented date arithmetic more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: You can remove the GNU dependency from this answer by using `this_month=$(date +%m)` and `next_month=$(( ${this_month#0} % 12 + 1 ))`, but I'm not sure what the third line is supposed to do (GNU coreutils 8.28 complains about an "extra operand"). Sticking a `-d` or `--date=` again makes this dependent on GNU.

Comment: I'm not trying to avoid GNU `date` altogether, just its more exotic arguments to `--date` (which, yes, I forgot as usual).

Answer (score 0):

What variant and version of `date` are you running?  "Solaris 5.2" was never released, though SunOS 5.2 was a kernel in Solaris 2.2 (EOL in 1999).  See the [Solaris OS version history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris_(operating_system)#Version_history).  The Solaris 10 (SunOS 5.10) [man page for date](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5165/6mbb0m9dc/index.html) does not support GNU's `--date=` syntax used in the question, so I'm guessing you're using some version of [date from GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Examples-of-date.html).

Here's a solution using BSD `date` (note, this is academic in the face of BSD's `date -v 1m`):

```
date -jf %s $((1728000+$(date -jf %Y-%m-%d $(date +%Y-%m-15) +%s))) +"%B %Y"
```

There are three date calls here.  BSD's date allows specifying a format (GNU can intuit most formats on its own).  The parent call is the one that takes the final time (as seconds since the 1970 epoch), expressing it in the desired "Month Year" format.  Seconds are determine by adding 20 days to the epoch time of the current month on the 15th day.  Since no month has 15+20 days, this is always the following month.

Here's a direct translation of that logic to GNU date:

```
date +"%B %Y" --date="@$((1728000+$(date +%s --date=$(date +%Y-%m-15))))"
```

Here's a simpler solution using GNU date, with one fewer `date` call:

```
date +"%B %Y" --date="$(date +%Y-%m-15) 20 days"
```

(A [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22764358/getting-next-month-with-date-command/22764898#22764898) in GNU date will give you the wrong month if you run `date --date="next month"` on the 31st.)

Answer (score 0):

The below one works in Red Hat 4.4.7-23, Linux version 2.6.32-754.2.1.el6.x86_64.
Just use the "month" for future months and "month ago" for previous months.. Dont confuse with adding +/- signs to the number. Check out.

```
> date "+%B-%Y"  #current month
November-2018
> date -d" 1 month" "+%B-%Y"
December-2018
> date -d" 1 month ago" "+%B-%Y"
October-2018
>
```

More..

```
> date -d" 7 month ago" "+%B-%Y"
April-2018
>  date -d" 7 month " "+%B-%Y"
June-2019
>
```